# mp3 audio file streaming server

Tags: node.js, flutter, go

I have mp3 file server that hosted nearly 1 Terabit.

And then our Android and iOS App Music player stream the file using http URL. So it download the whole file and costing lot of bandwidth.

Most of the file play duration is nearly 1 hour average and around 20Mb. So now App user is increasing and the bandwidth is around 30Terabit per month.

It is eating our client alive. So they want us to redesign the architecture.

So I'm thinking to chunk the mp3 to HLS file and call the m3u8 instead of mp3.

Is this a correct way of doing? Is there any other way around.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: A little unclear on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to reduce the overall data transfer amount per month? HLS will not really solve this - unless most of your users are not listening to your files completely.

Comment: Yes, I want to reduce the data transfer amount. Now, every time user play the audio, it will download the whole file. Instead of simply calling the file URL from server, is there any workaround or which technologies can I use. By the way, App is developed by flutter and api server is Go. File server is simply using Nginx on Linux.

Comment: It does not matter if you stream in chunks or download the whole file at once. The file content must be sent to the client, how you do this does not matter for the bandwich. Your client have to live with that if he dont want to host the content/files local. A possible way would be compression like, gzip, etc. but not sure if the benefits are great enough.

Comment: Webrtc, right now, might be your only solution. But implementing it to achieve what you want - while possible to a certain extent - will not be trivial at all. If this is absolutely the route you must take try looking for existing webrtc libraries/services. If bandwidth costs are a concern maybe evaluate providers like cloudflare.

Comment: Thanks Marc and Kelsnare for your comment. I will do the research.